# Google maps version change freezes website - v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Edit: The site is working properly again.  I deleted the line of code flagged by commentors below (referencing a nonexistent div), experimented with version syntax, and also with the order of parameters in my contentBox function).  Also deleted the  syntax and added a line of code to call the function from the DOM.  Thanks to all who commented.  Some combination of the above worked.  Cheers, Cheryl)**

Note: I asked this question in the main forum yesterday -- didn't realize that the google maps user group had its own tag in Stack Overflow.  Here's the Q:

I have an application that uses Google maps API v. 3 and accesses content from a database to display in google's infowindows and a sidebar. See the code for the main file here: www.corkmemorymap.org.

My problem is that, periodically, the function that brings up content in the sidebar when a user clicks on a marker stops working. You can still access sidebar content via the topic search at the top of the page (that is done with jquery, and not tied to google or the markers) but I can't get sidebar content through the markers.

The last time this happened, it was a version issue. I added a version to the script code that calls the API, and all was well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&sensor=false"></script>
```

This time I thought it was the same thing, as I saw Google had deprecated that version. So I updated to the new version and... nada. So now I am stumped. I tried messing around with different versions, or no version, and had it briefly working again. Then not. Does anyone else have experience with this? Are the versions unstable? Any suggestions?

If it helps, this is the function that calls the change in sidebar content:

```
function contentBox(marker, map, sidebar, winHtml, infoWindow) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML=winHtml;
        infoWindow.close(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Oh, one other thing -- I'm not using an API key as this is a non-profit website.  Do I need an API key (it's been working without one since December 2011)? Is there anything tricky about them?

Regards, Cheryl

Comment: Firebug shows this error:                    document.getElementById("infoWindow") is null

Comment: This is likely not related to the root cause of your problem, but you probably want the version specifier set to: `v=3.8`. The [Versioning section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) gives more detail if you scroll down to **Choosing an API Version**, but 3.9 is the _Nightly_ version and production apps should use the _Release_ version. Hope this is helpful-

Comment: There's also this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/cnfp/main.js"></script>` -- what's that about? That doesn't work on my machine as I'm not running a webserver. If that's a local copy of Google's Maps API, that **will** cause problems.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I wasn't sure which version to use, though you're right, that isn't the root cause of the freeze!  Andrew, that main.js file is where i've stored the jquery functions -- they run the topic search and that is working.  I don't understand the firebug error as the infoWindows are displaying.  It is the sidebar content that doesn't display, at least not on marker click.  thanks for looking though!

Comment: @Cheryl: The page is referencing `localhost`. That will only work when *you* run the page on *your* webserver. My browser can't get a file off `localhost`. The Firebug error is that you don't have an HTML Element with `id='infoWindow'`.

Comment: oops! I uploaded my development copy yesterday trying to fix the version prob.  Well-spotted!  Will fix that pronto. And I'll look at that 'infoWindow' issue.  Not sure why that would suddenly change but maybe my code was not stable.  cheers,

Comment: Hi lads, if anyone is still on this thread, I fixed the issue with the local server misdirect and commented out the line of code referring to a nonexistent div.  Still have the content freeze in the sidebar.  Now that the topic search works, you can see what is supposed to happen there when a user clicks a marker. I'm really stumped here.  Ideas welcome, cheers,

Comment: Congrats, I see that it´s working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in comments above.  There were two issues: I needed to update the version of the Google Maps API I was referencing in the header, and I had a line of code pointing to a  nonexistent div.  I updated the former and deleted the latter.  Thanks to those who responded.